# Scroll Div to Bottom in Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic page in which I have a scrollable div.

```
<div #list class="main">
    <div class="row-container" *ngFor="let log of logs">
        <p class="log">{{log.guess}}  -  {{log.result}}</p>
        <div class="score-container">
            <ion-icon name="star" style="color: gold;"></ion-icon>
            <p class="score">{{log.score}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class of the div:

```
.main {
    height: 90%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I want to automatically scroll to the bottom of the div when the page loads and also when a new item is added to the list.

So far I have tried to use `@ViewChild('list') list:any;` to get the element. Then:

```
this.list.scrollTop = this.list.scrollHeight;
```

and

```
this.list.scrollToBottom(100);
```

But `scrollTop` just does not work. `scrollToBottom` threw an error that stated scrollToBottom was not a function.

How can I scroll to the bottom of the div?

Comment: el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight; should work, you have any errors? Is your element (list) of correct type? list should be an HTMLElement to have these properties available.

Comment: I logged the list item and this was the result: `ElementRef {nativeElement: div.main, scrollTop: undefined}`

Comment: Try to cast it as HTMLElement.

Comment: I changed `@ViewChild('list') list:any;` to `@ViewChild('list') list:HTMLElement;`. There was no change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add [scrollTop] to Template side. I found it easier to implement.

```
<div #list class="main" [scrollTop]="list.scrollHeight">
<div class="row-container" *ngFor="let log of logs">
    <p class="log">{{log.guess}}  -  {{log.result}}</p>
    <div class="score-container">
        <ion-icon name="star" style="color: gold;"></ion-icon>
        <p class="score">{{log.score}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```